# jquery select input whose name starts with x or y

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a page that is filled with `radiobuttonlists` whose IDs start with either "inc" or "exc" for inclusion/exclusion questions. I am able to select all the inclusion buttons with `$('input[name^="inc"]')` and all the exclusions with `$('input[name^="exc"]')`. Since I am binding both types of buttons with the same function I wanted to combine my select statement to grab both sets of elements.

I tried `$('input[name^="inc|exc"]')` but this doesn't select anything. I tested that it found nothing by looking at the length and it is zero. I tried a couple other ways but they all result in no matches.

To sum up the problem, using jquery, I need to find all inputs whose name start with "inc" or "exc"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('input[name^=inc], input[name^=exc]');
```

Comment: well herp the derp batman, thanks. completely forgot you could use a separator there to include more selection.

Comment: @peroija Welcome, accepting any helpful answer is greatest thanks to answerer.

Comment: This is it +1. Just to add, jQuery follows the css convention to `select` dom elements. Like css we select more than 1 set of elements by separating by comma :)

Comment: @thecodeparadox without a doubt, we just have to wait 15 minutes before we can mark an answer :P